# I'm new to this coding language, Json parsing troubleshooting

Tags: objective-c, json

I have followed some courses and got to a stage where I nearly have what I want. I'll add the section of code below with the error that needs fixing. Its probably really easy to fix its just that I'm new to this and I have no idea what I'm doing.
error: `Expected method to read dictionary element not found on object of type 'NSMutableArray *'`
This probably isn't the most efficient way of doing this and don't use any over complicated words or phrases to help cut ima not understand them. If anyone could just fix the code that'll be really useful. and thank you.

```
NSError *error;
NSString *url_string = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"https://******/latest.json"];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:url_string]];
NSMutableArray *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions        error:&error];
NSLog(@"json: %@", json);
NSString *BGmmol = json[@"mmol"];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store the parsing result in a dictionary:

```
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions];
```